# Express symmetric double integral in terms of single integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Is it possible to express the following double integral using only a single integral?
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)f(y)}{ia-x-y}dxdy,
$$
where $a$ is real.
Are there any general theorems that make this procedure easier in general?

Comment: $\ldots=\int_0^\infty e^{iat}\hat{f}^2(t)\,dt$ where $\hat{f}(t)=\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}f(x)\,dx$.